# How to use the Util and Base Code of the General Mission Analysis Tool

Tags: mission-design, gmat, api

GMAT (General Mission Analysis Tool) provides detailed Util and Base Code, but I don't know how to use it, namely I still don't know how to access so many data of some missions. Can somebody provide some examples about usage of GMAT API?

Comment: What documentation have you read so far? Have you found any specific examples on line that you'd like some help understanding? Anything you can add to your question along these lines may increase the chance of getting an answer. *Thanks!*

Comment: I know nearly all the examples provided with its documents. but it can only give part usages, not deep reference for my problem. I don't know how to find the answer from the documents.

Comment: An current problem is as follow :